# Can the Loadrunner Controller be run on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, loadrunner

Obviously, we are several years behind, but we want to get rid of our Loadrunner physical infrastructure --- Our Controller machines as well as our Generators. We are setting up our own EC2 instances to do this. Questions have arisen already:

1) Can we even run the Loadrunner 12.6x Controller in AWS?
2) If we do try to run it, how do we deal with the Microfocus License process? i.e., It seems we need to gather the Microfocus Loadrunner Host ID, then go download the License, and then install it. Each time we spin up the Controller, we have to start all over again.
3) To provision a Loadrunner Generator in AWS we need a Certificate. We have never needed that before. Where do we get it?

If Jim (Pulley) sees this, he will likely tell me to go talk with Microfocus. That is way, way easier to say than to do. I have had at least three SR's with them, and they seem totally lost on the whole topic of AWS. They seem even more lost with their own licensing process. I keep having to rehost my License and screw around on their support site for Entitlements and Downloads.

If Wilson Mars sees this, please call me and talk me through this mess.

Thanks,
Randy

Comment: I am sorry you couldn't get a decent answer until now. Could you please send this text to the VuGen feedback email? In VuGen, go to help -> send us your feedback. I will make sure the proper people take a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need a worldwide access licence for your controller as it will be outside of your corporate campus and you will be accessing it remote.   This is an easier path than performance center.  There are still a lot of goofy holdovers in the comp plans based upon geographic location of the controller that should not impact you as a customer, but since they impact salesperson compensation they come into play.

There are a couple of other models you might consider:

- Leave your controller internal and move all of your load generation to Amazon or other cloud providers.  Depending upon where your app under load is located you could have some issues in hitting your app without some firewall rules in play.  I work to negotiate a unique HTTP header that the firewall recognizes to allow clean passing.  I would recommend leaving one load generator in-house as a control element for your tests.
- Consider Stormrunner Load (or is it now LoadRunner cloud??).  I know of at least one customer who took their total number of testing hours by protocol on Performance Center and were able to negotiate a Stormrunner Load license for less than the forthcoming maintenance on their Performance Center instance.  This also left the Performance Center instance in place as a perpetual license, ***but not under support***, for the odd protocol not yet supported on Stormrunner Load.

Unfortunately you are going to need to involve your Microfocus VAR or SalesRep as you navigate this path.  Only one of the models doesn't involve a likely license impact.  That remaining one would be to leave the controller in place with a move of your load generators to the cloud.   Hopefully this provides some number of options that you can take to your rep for information on exactly what would be the financial impact of each option.